# Get data from fmp12-file?

Tags: filemaker

I got handed a USB-stick with a Filemaker (`.fmp12`) file. There was also a bunch of images, xml-files and corresponding `._`-files. It is supposed to be an browsable image-archive with image meta-data. I'm expected to extract the information and incorporate it into another site. But I have no experience or licence for filemaker so I do not know howto.

Is it possible to get hold of the content somehow, or is my only option to purchase a licence of Filemaker just to export the data to some friendlier format?

Comment: The free trial might give you enough time to export. You'll have to export each table manually. While ODBC is an option, it uses an archaic format (SQL-92) and I don't recommend spending your time on ODBC.

Comment: The free trial will enable you to open the file -  but to export the data you will need export privileges. These could be restricted by the developer to full-access accounts or even removed altogether, if this is a runtime (as it would seem).

Comment: FileMaker file is a binary, so there is no other way to extract info apart from using FileMaker. Trial is probably your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the free, trial version of FileMaker Pro Advanced 17.
You may need 'full access' privileges or at least login credentials that allow exporting. There may not be a login required, however.